# Haskell Leijen pretty-printer, can't handle indentation

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm working on a pretty-printer for Lua, and I'm stuck with handling indentation for function syntax.

What I want is this: if function definition is short enough, all definition could be written in one line, but if it's not that short, then all *body* is needed to be printed in new line and with indentation. After that, `end` keyword should be placed in a new line, without indentation.

I think I don't fully understand how Leijen pretty-printer works, but this is what I've got so far:

```
import Text.PrettyPrint.Leijen
import System.IO (stdout)

sometext = text "short text" </> text "this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes"
p = parens (align (cat (punctuate (comma <> space) (map text ["first parameter", "second parameter", "third"]))))

doc3 = indent 4 (sep [text "function" </> p, indent 4 sometext, text "end"])

main :: IO ()
main = do
    displayIO stdout (renderPretty 1 133 (doc3 <$> line))
    displayIO stdout (renderPretty 1 134 (doc3 <$> line))
    displayIO stdout (renderPretty 1 40 (doc3 <$> line))
```

This actually works pretty well except the second part of the output:

```
function (first parameter, second parameter, third)
    short text this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
end

function (first parameter, second parameter, third)     short text this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes end

function (first parameter, 
          second parameter, 
          third)
    short text
    this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
end
```

Here I don't want that 4 spaces indentation, in second output. But I couldn't find a way to do that without ruining other outputs.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's another test case:

```
doc4 = sep [ text "if" </> text "test" </> text "then"
           , indent 4 then_body
           , text "elseif" </> elseif_conditions </> text "then"
           , indent 4 elseif_body
           , text "end"
           ]
```

What I want from it is, if the output is short enough, print all of it at the same line(but without indentation spaces). It works great when splitting multiple lines, but puts superfluous spaces when prints to same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's make a way of trying out documents at every width starting with a maximum, and only print the ones that are different. This will help check the Doc behaves as you hope.

```
import Text.PrettyPrint.Leijen
import System.IO (stdout)
import Data.List
import Data.Function

testFrom :: Int -> Doc -> IO ()
testFrom w d = mapM_ printone . nubBy ((==) `on` snd) .map (`showAt` d). reverse $ [1..w] where
   showAt n doc = (n,displayS (renderPretty 1 n doc) "")
   printone (n,xs) = putStrLn (show n ++ ":") >> putStrLn xs
```

### What I (now) think you want

Now let's take advantage of the extra info in your comments. Sorry I misinterpreted you the first time round.

I think you mean it's permissible to all be on one line, but if not, there should be at least three, with the function head on the first, the function body indented and the end unindented. You don't mind if the `sometext` is split across lines at the break, comes after the parameters etc, as long as it's indented by 4 if it's not inline.

The `nest` function allows us to indent subsequent lines if there are any, whereas `indent` definitely puts spaces, which is why you had the ugly extra 4 lines.

So, there are three parts to your function:

```
functionhead = text "function" </> p
sometext = text "short text" 
           </> text "this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes"
end = text "end"
```

with a slightly refactored way of making parameters:

```
params = parens.align.cat.punctuate (comma <> space).map text 
p = params ["first parameter", "second parameter", "third"]
```

### Lay it out with the breaks specified

Let's specify how we'd like them laid out if we need line breaks:

```
tidyfunction = nest 4 (functionhead <$> sometext) <$> end
```

Which demonstrates the way we want the line breaks to go:

```
*Main> testFrom 140 tidy
140:
function (first parameter, second parameter, third)
    short text this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
end
73:
function (first parameter, second parameter, third)
    short text
    this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
end
50:
function (first parameter, 
          second parameter, 
          third)
    short text
    this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
end
26:
function
    (first parameter, 
     second parameter, 
     third)
    short text
    this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
end
```

### Pop it all on one line if it fits

The pretty printing library has a combinator for getting rid of all line breaks if it fits on one line, `group`. Let's indent the whole lot by 4 and group.

```
nicefunction = group $ indent 4 tidyfunction
```

Which gives:

```
*Main> testFrom 140 nicefunction
140:
    function (first parameter, second parameter, third) short text this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes end
129:
    function (first parameter, second parameter, third)
        short text this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
    end
77:
    function (first parameter, second parameter, third)
        short text
        this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
    end
54:
    function (first parameter, 
              second parameter, 
              third)
        short text
        this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
    end
30:
    function
        (first parameter, 
         second parameter, 
         third)
        short text
        this is some long text at least long enough for my purposes
    end
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I want, in your third output, `end` should be at same line with others(or if it will be long enough, they should be separated by newlines). I think only way to do this is putting `doc "end"` in the same `sep` list with function head and function body, but this time `nest` ruins the indentation(it indents `end`).

Comment: it should skip from the second to the fifth.

Comment: @sinan Complete rewrite. What do you think?

Comment: great, many thanks. this also demonstrates me the use of `<$>` with `group`.